# Error using fsolve: trust region with non-square system

Tags: matlab

I have the following function which I am defining some of the parameters as follows:

```
function F = solar5d(x)    
    q = 1.60217662*10^-19;    
    k = 1.38064852*10^-23;    
    T = 298.15; % Temperature in degrees 25. This one is in Kelvin.    
    Ns = 72;    
    Np = 1;    
    Voc = 44.6;    
    Vm = 35.43;    
    Isc = 5.43;    
    Im = 4.95;    
    n = 1.086;    
    % These are my unknown parameters I am looking for:    
    Iph = x(1);    
    Io = x(2);    
    Rs = x(3);    
    Rp = x(4);    
    Vt = x(5);    
    % The following are the six questions I have to solve the system:    
    F(1) = Vt - n*k*T/q;    
    F(2) = Np*Iph - Np*Io*(exp(Voc/Ns*Vt)-1) - (Np*Voc)/(Ns*Rp);    
    F(3) = Np*Iph - Np*Io*(exp((Isc*Rs)/(Np*Vt)) - 1) - (Isc*Rs)/Rp -     Isc;    
    F(4) = Np*Iph - Np*Io*(exp(((Vm/Ns)+(Im*Rs)/Np)/Vt) - 1) - Np*((((Vm/Ns)+((Im*Rs)/Np))/Rp)) - Im;    
    F(5) = (((Np/Ns*Vt)*Io*(exp((Vm + ((Im*Ns*Rs)/Np))/Ns*Vt)) +   (1/(Ns*Rp)/Np))/(1 + (Rs*Vt)*Io*(exp((Vm + ((Im*Ns*Rs)/Np))/Ns*Vt)) + (Rs/Rp))) - (Im/Vm);        
    F(6) = (((-Np/Ns*Vt)*Io*(exp(Voc/Ns*Vt)) - (1/Ns*Rp/Np)) / (1 + (Rs/Vt)*Io*(exp(Voc/Ns*Vt)) + (Rs/Rp))) + 1/Rs;    
end
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> Warning: Trust-region-dogleg algorithm of FSOLVE cannot handle
> non-square systems; using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm instead. > In
> fsolve (line 298) Error using levenbergMarquardt (line 16) Objective
> function is returning undefined values at initial point. fsolve cannot
> continue.
>
> Error in fsolve (line 397) levenbergMarquardt(funfcn,x,verbosity,options,defaultopt,f,JAC,caller, ...

Please could you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't even use `fsolve`...

Comment: I am calling the following in the command window:   fun = @solar5d;  x0= [0,0,0,0,0];   x = fsolve(fun,x0)